# C# Get the current URL using .Net portable

Tags: c#, .net

Bear with me if this is a dumb question I am new to C#.

What I am trying to do is get the current URL, preferably using only what is available from .Net Portable v4.0.

So far I have tried:

```
String test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 

String test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.toString();
```

But both of these require adding references to System.Web. I always get the following error:

> The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

And I've completed all the suggestion online but nothing fixes it.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: what version of the project are you writing this in ..? .net 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5..? also the error is self explanatory if you are creating a winforms application then you need to add the reference to `System.Web` both in the project as well as in the using at the top of the class so please state if this is a winforms or a web forms application

Comment: @MethodMan I'm using .net 4.0 and I did add references to System.Web in the project and the top of the class, and I even added an assembly reference in the app.config file

Comment: Adding System.Web to app.config won't affect the project.  What are the project references to your project from the Solution Explorer?

Comment: .NETPortable,v4.0,
System.Web, System.Net.Http,